# Google Cloud Sql Connection with ssl in c#

Tags: c#, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to connect my google cloud SQL Server with SSL in c#. But I'm getting a Argument Exception error for "driver, sslca, sslcert and sslkey" keywords.

How can I connect my database to use SSL?

```
 string connStr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver}; Server=35.148.120.30; User = myuser; Password = mypass; sslca = ../sql_pem/server-ca.pem; sslcert = ../sql_pem/client-cert.pem; sslkey = ../sql_pem/client-key.pem; sslverify = 1; Option = 3; ";
 MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
 MySqlCommand cmd;
 string s0;

 try
 {
     conn.Open();
     s0 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `hello97`;";
     cmd = new MySqlCommand(s0, conn);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     conn.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception es)
  {

  }
```

**Error**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Keyword not supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect Google Cloud SQL with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457709/how-to-connect-google-cloud-sql-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Connector/NET, the valid connection string options are [listed here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html):

- **Driver** - don't need this; it's implied by the library/class you're using
- **sslca** - not supported by Connector/NET, but if you switch to [MySqlConnector](http://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) you can use `CACertificateFile`
- **sslcert**, **sslkey** - convert these to a pfx file [as described here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl.html) then use the `CertificateFile` option.